# Is Appcelerator Studio working on Node version > 0.12

Tags: node.js, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

As of today, I checked the Node.js website. They offer Node version 4.4.0 right now.

Do you know if I installed this new version, would it works with the IDE?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Appcelerator Studio works fine with NodejS 4.4.0